# При запуске Jupyter запрашивает ввод пароля или токена

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке войти, запрашивает токен или пароль.

Никогда, ничего до этого не вводила. Пробовала сделать все по инструкции, но все равно запрашивает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Команда:

```
jupyter notebook list
```

покажет `token`, который надо будет ввести (он будет сохранен в `cookies`, поэтому второй раз его вводить не придется).

[здесь подробнее об этом...](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/1831)

Comment: пробовала так делать, выдает , что сервер не найден или снова запрашивает пароль или токен

Comment: получилось, ввела команду 

jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.token=''